# How to hide a scrollbar? (Windows Mobile)

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, scrollbar

I have one panel "imageHolder"
I have from 4 to 20 pictureboxes (each pictureBox is 256x256px so they increase the panel's size to more than the cellphone's workarea)
I have set the panel's autoscroll = true, so that a V and H scrollbar is shown.

Is it possible to make these scrollbars not visible?

The reason i want them to be not visible:
- I want to be able to use touch to move around in the panel, and thought that i can do this by just increasing/decreasing the scrollbar's position.

Is there a way to do this? (I have searched, but can't seem to find anything useful. Looks like the scrollbars are a bit limited)

Do you recommend me to do it some other way?

Comment: did you have to postit twice?

Comment: did you have to postit twice?

Comment: let's keep this one open and close the other one

Comment: sorry, there was some problems with my browser....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of a hack, but you could just make the panel bigger than the viewable area so that the scroll bars are off the screen...

Answer (score 0):

you could just change the autoscroll property to false.

Comment: But then i won't be able to "move" to the other pictureBoxes

Comment: I guess u could use the touch control example shown in the fluid controls shown at http://fluid.codeplex.com/ don't know if that might help. It has no scroll bar there